# How to add validation for nested Array of objects

Tags: laravel

I'm validating my API request in Laravel controller.  It consists of an array of objects that each of the item needed to be validated.

I tried the nested array validation and tried creating a separate request validation class but was not able to succeed.

```
{
    "total" : 250.00,
    "merchant_id" : 1,
    "discount" : 0,
    "items" :  {
        [id: 1, quantity: 25, notes: "some string A"],
        [id: 2, quantity: 10, notes: "some string B"],
        [id: 3, quantity: 5, notes: "some string C"]
    }
}
```

Each parameter of the main object (total, merchant_id, discount) and also the nested array parameters (id, quantity, notes) needed to be validated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.*` notation as specified in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Let's say all of them are required. you can validate it like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'total' => 'required',
    'merchant_id' => 'required',
    'discount' => 'required',
    'items.*.id' => 'required',
    'items.*.quantity' => 'required',
    'items.*.notes' => 'required',
]);
```